# Is there a way to restrict the application of OrderBy on ng-repeat in AngularJs selectively?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

In my application I am iterating over an array whose values that are bound to textboxes(basically input type="number"). i.e.,

say,

```
<div ng-repeat="number in numbers|orderBy:'value'">
     <input type="number" ng-model="number.value">
</div>
```

This Plnkr link - http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&s=D7hhm2al6sOXMHwQ

demonstrates what I am talking about.

So as soon as I change the value of the  the textboxes are reordered. I don't want this to happen as it creates discomfort for my users who have to search for the box they just edited. 
I want a solution where the ng-repeat is ordered the first time the doms are created but not ordered again until they are recreated. How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by ordering your array once in your `controller`, in this case by injecting `$filter`. Do this after you've loaded `$scope.numbers`, obviously.

```
.controller('myController', function($filter, $scope){
    $scope.numbers = $filter('orderBy')($scope.numbers, 'value')
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked Beautifully :)

Comment: are you sure ? I just added it in your pluncker and it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Eagle1 the code was not intended to be plug and play in the plunkr, just to demonstrate how you might order the array once on load, and then not have it dynamically reorder. The application of the method is left as an experiment for the reader.

Comment: oh I understand the code now, I was too fast reading it. actually it can be pluged&play, just have to remove the orderBy in the HTML